# Coq Index Relation

Tags: coq, dependent-type

I'm defining an indexed inductive type in Coq:

```
Module Typ.

  (* My index -- a t is a `t H` or a `t Z`. *)
  Inductive hz : Set := H | Z .

  (* I'd like to use this relation to constrain Cursor and Arrow. *)
  (* E.g. one specialized Cursor has type `t H -> t Z -> t Z` *)
  Inductive maxHZ : hz -> hz -> hz -> Type :=
  | HZ : maxHZ H Z Z
  | ZH : maxHZ Z H Z
  | HH : maxHZ H H H
  .

  Inductive t : hz -> Type := 
  | Num : t H
  | Hole : t H
  | Cursor : t H -> t Z
  | Arrow : forall a b c, t a -> t b -> t c
  | Sum   : forall a b c, t a -> t b -> t c
  .
End Typ.
```

How can I constrain my `Arrow` / `Sum` indices to be the same shape as the `maxHZ` relation (short of creating more constructors, like `ArrowHZ : t H -> t Z -> t Z`).

Comment: Depending on your final use case, you could either create a subtype of `t` and make `Arrow` satisfy the `maxHZ` predicate, or alternatively, you could add the relation to the constructor `Arrow : forall a b c, maxHZ a b c -> t a -> t b -> t c`. In all cases, you want to make `maxHZ` irrelevant so it doesn't bug you in proofs. Making it a boolean is likely a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

```
(* Bring the coercion is_true into scope *)
From Coq Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool.

Module Typ.

  (* My index -- a t is a `t H` or a `t Z`. *)
  Inductive hz : Set := H | Z .

  (* I'd like to use this relation to constrain Cursor and Arrow. *)
  (* E.g. one specialized Cursor has type `t H -> t Z -> t Z` *)
  Definition maxHZ (x y z : hz) : bool :=
    match x, y, z with
    | H, Z, Z
    | Z, H, Z
    | H, H, H => true
    | _, _, _ => false
    end.

  Inductive t : hz -> Type :=
  | Num  : t H
  | Hole : t H
  | Cursor : t H -> t Z
  | Arrow : forall a b c, maxHZ a b c -> t a -> t b -> t c
  | Sum   : forall a b c, maxHZ a b c -> t a -> t b -> t c
  .
End Typ.
```

the other:

```
  Inductive t : hz -> Type :=
  | Num  : t H
  | Hole : t H
  | Cursor : t H -> t Z
  | Arrow : forall a b c, t a -> t b -> t c
  | Sum   : forall a b c, t a -> t b -> t c
  .

  Definition t_wf x (m : t x) : bool :=
    match m with
    | Arrow a b c _ _ => maxHZ a b c
    | Sum   a b c _ _ => maxHZ a b c
    | _ => true
    end.

  Definition t' x := { m : t x | t_wf x m }.
  (* This is automatically a subtype. *)
```

Comment: Why do you redefine `maxHZ` as a function to `bool` instead of keeping it like it is and having the constraint `maxHZ a b c` in the `Arrow` constructor?

Comment: To get irrelevance for free, I don't want equality on `t` to depend on the concrete shape / proof of the relation.